# type '(List<String>) => Null' is not a subtype of type '((List<String?>) => dynamic)?' in Multi_select_flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I used multi_select_flutter and I got errors. I do not know what I am missing. Below is my code.

```
                List<String>? sectionIds = [];
                final _items = sections
                 .map(
                     (section) => MultiSelectItem<String>(
                      section,
                      section.toUpperCase(),
                  ),
                )
               .toList();
                MultiSelectChipField(
                  items: _items,
                  initialValue: sectionIds,
                  title: const Text("Section"),
                  headerColor: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                        color: const Color(0xFF059CD1), width: 1.8),
                  ),
                  selectedChipColor: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5),
                  selectedTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue[800]),
                  onTap: (List<String> values) {
                    sectionIds = values;
                    //_selectedAnimals4 = values;
                  },
                ),
```

Error occurred:
type '(List) => Null' is not a subtype of type '((List<String?>) => dynamic)?'
Please why did this error occur?

Comment: Probably a null safety concern ! 
Where does the error occurs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to change `List<String> values` to `List<String?> values`:

```
                List<String>? sectionIds = [];
                final _items = sections
                 .map(
                     (section) => MultiSelectItem<String>(
                      section,
                      section.toUpperCase(),
                  ),
                )
               .toList();
                MultiSelectChipField(
                  items: _items,
                  initialValue: sectionIds,
                  title: const Text("Section"),
                  headerColor: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                        color: const Color(0xFF059CD1), width: 1.8),
                  ),
                  selectedChipColor: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5),
                  selectedTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue[800]),
                  onTap: (List<String?> values) {
                    sectionIds = values;
                    //_selectedAnimals4 = values;
                  },
                ),
```